# jersey/Mockito: NullInsteadOfMockException on client.post call verification

Tags: java, jersey, mockito

I've run into a strange issue with unit testing the following jersey client call:

```
WebResource webResource = _client.resource(url);
ClientResponse response = webResource
                        .accept("application/json")
                        .type("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                        .post(ClientResponse.class, postBody);
```

PostBody is a MultivaluedMap.

The unit test verifies fine the `accept` and `type` calls but fails on the `post` one with this exception:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NullInsteadOfMockException: 
Argument passed to verify() should be a mock but is null!
```

Here's the test code:

```
_client = Mockito.mock(Client.class);
        _webResource = Mockito.mock(WebResource.class);
        _builder = Mockito.mock(WebResource.Builder.class);
        _response = Mockito.mock(ClientResponse.class);

        Mockito.when(_client.resource(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(_webResource);

        Mockito.when(_response.getEntity(Mockito.any(Class.class))).thenReturn(new RefreshTokenDto());
        Mockito.when(_response.getStatus()).thenReturn(200);

        Mockito.when(_builder.post(Mockito.eq(ClientResponse.class), Mockito.anyObject())).thenReturn(_response);
        Mockito.when(_builder.type(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(_builder);
        Mockito.when(_webResource.accept(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(_builder);

        RefreshTokenDto response = _clientWrapper.exchangeAuthorizationCodeForToken(_token);

        Assert.assertNotNull(response);

        Mockito.verify(_client.resource(_baseUrl + "token"));
        Mockito.verify(_webResource.accept("application/json"));
        Mockito.verify(_builder.type("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

        // TODO: this line throws NullRefExc for some unknown reason
        Mockito.verify(_builder.post(Mockito.any(Class.class), Mockito.any(MultivaluedMap.class)));
```

Can you see anything wrong with this code?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes.  You've misused `verify`.  The argument to `verify` has to be the mock itself.  Then you call the method you want to verify on the value that's returned by `verify`.  So in this case, the first `verify` call should be

```
Mockito.verify(_client).resource(_baseUrl + "token");
```

and similarly for the other `verify` calls.

Comment: Hey - that indeed solves the issue! I confused the syntax for `when` and `verify`. I've been looking at this code since yesterday and couldn't figure out what was wrong. It probably shows that I'm new to mockito. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Dawood, thanks your answer, that solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue, but for `when()` instead of `verify()`. I found this question by googling. For me, I had forgotten to add [`MockitoAnnotations.initMocks()`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.28/org/mockito/MockitoAnnotations.html#initMocks(java.lang.Object)) in my test class' constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Had this error because of a wrong call to verify I made. I used

```
verify(mock.methodToVerify, times(n));
```

instead of

```
verify(mock, times(n)).methodToVerify();
```